# CMake PkgConfig doesn't work

Tags: cmake, glfw, pkg-config

This works:

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags glfw3
```

but

```
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt does not work. Error message:

```
-- checking for one of the modules 'glfw3'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:548 (message):
  None of the required 'glfw3' found
```

I compiled CMake 3.2.3 for Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
pkg_check_modules (GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
if (NOT GLFW_FOUND)
# put error here
endif ()
```